# How to enable button onClick functions and java script in wordpress post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to add the below codes to Wordpress, however, wordpress always gives me error 404 whenever I try to update. I'm new to coding. So would appreciate some help.

[image: Codes that I want to add into wordpress post]

[image: Image of my error]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>

</head>
<body>


  Code 1: <input type="text" id="code1">
  <br>
  <p id="code1ans"></p>

  Code 2: <input type="text" id="code2">
  <br>
  <p id="code2ans"></p>

  Code 3: <input type="text" id="code3">
  <br>
  <p id="code3ans"></p>

  Code 4: <input type="text" id="code4">
  <br>
  <p id="code4ans"></p>


  <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
          var code1 = document.getElementById("code1").value;
          var code2 = document.getElementById("code2").value;
          var code3 = document.getElementById("code3").value;
          var code4 = document.getElementById("code4").value;
          document.getElementById("code1ans").innerHTML = code1;
          document.getElementById("code2ans").innerHTML = code2;
          document.getElementById("code3ans").innerHTML = code3;
         document.getElementById("code4ans").innerHTML = code4;
      }
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Do you mean that without the code you added you don't have the 404, but by adding a few lines of js in a <script> you get a 404?

Comment: That's right, as long as I added these the code below and the scripts, error 404 would appear.

 "<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>...

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses the [template hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/), so I'm guessing you want this code to execute on a specific page or perhaps you want it to run on every page load?

Wordpress uses a system of hooks called filters and actions to run things at certain times. One of them is https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts which allows you to load scripts. Here you can also add code run the script only on specific pages. You should add your script here based on the documentation.

Your question doesn't appear to specify where you are putting your code.